# How can old pages be identified in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is there any way to list pages that have not been updated for a long time in MediaWiki?  Is there an extension or other functionality to do this?

Ideally I'd like to be able to e.g. list all pages that have not been updated for 12 months (ie based on last edit).  They are then by default considered old (could even add a tag - an {{Old}} template - to the top of the page to flag it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is, more or less; go into the "special pages" (menu on the left) and you'll find the list of oldest pages.

Comment: This is funny - I always assumed this list was based on the creation date but actually it is indeed the last edited date.  Great that this is built in - thanks - this is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at:

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Stale_Pages

Comment: This is good but it seems to be a special case of Special:AncientPages (MediaWiki's word for Old pages).  But it is useful (in that you can define exactly what "old" is).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the MediaWiki API at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Using the API it is possible to run commands like this http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges which would return the recent changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to use the API to get information from Special Pages, so you'd have to figure out how to get the oldest pages other than from the Special:Oldest. There is a bug about this: https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14869

Comment: Thanks Shaji and Adrian.  But the previous answers are sufficient.